# EntityFramework.Filters Dynamic Parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using [EntityFramework.Filters](https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters) package in order to set some defaults and dynamics filters to my entities. It's working well, but **Q: when I dynamically set a new filter parameter it's being ignored keeping the first value set**.

In debug mode `CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture().Key` is properly returning the new culture set, the filter parameter is being set, but nothing happens.

Code

```
public partial class DataModel : DbContext
{
    public DataModel() : base("name=DataModel")
    {
            var currentLanguageId = CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture().Key;
            this.EnableFilter("HideDeleted");
            this.EnableFilter("CurrentLanguage").SetParameter("currentLanguageId", currentLanguageId);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new FilterInterceptor());
        modelBuilder
            .Conventions
            .Add(
                FilterConvention.Create<IDeleted, int>("HideDeleted", (e, Deleted) => e.Deleted == false),
                FilterConvention.Create<ILanguage, long>("CurrentLanguage", (e, currentLanguageId) => e.LanguageId == currentLanguageId)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to make `currentLanguageId` static variable and use it instead of passing?

Comment: Yes I did @ASpirin, using as static works perfectly. Filter parameter is considering the first value set only.

Comment: What is the code under `CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture()`?

Comment: Exactly this `public static KeyValuePair<long, string> GetCurrentCulture()

        {

            var currentCultureCode = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;

            var currentCulture = _cultures.Where(c => c.Value == currentCultureCode).FirstOrDefault();


            return currentCulture;

        }`

Comment: Don't you think that accessing `_cultures` could force `ModelCreation`?

Comment: Just checked it's so. `ModelCreation` executed in another order. I would suggest to move the filter logic into `Expression` and enable field with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` parameter

Comment: @ASpirin I don't think so. Please have a look what `_culture` represents `private static readonly IDictionary<long, string> _cultures = new Dictionary<long, string> {
            { 2, "en" }, // English NEUTRAL culture

            { 3, "es" } // Spanish NEUTRAL culture

        };

`

Comment: Ahh, ok. Than why not to use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID` in your filter, that will be standartized and in case of language change in the app it would be changed at the same moment

Comment: Well... sounds a good suggestion. But in this case I would have to change my langs Ids to match with LCID... it's not going to be a big trouble in my case.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the reproducion rules. Check and debug the code

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce this issue only by accessing any Context property before enabling the filter in constructor, that causes `OnModelCreation` to be raised, **after `OnModelCreation` was raised there is no possibility to setup the filter**. Debug you `OnModelCreation`, and define what causes `ModelCreation` before you filter is enabled. Just set a breakpoints to Constructor and `OnModelCreation` and you'll see when `OnModelCreation`is actually started.

Filtering is applyed to the set of objects. Interceptor is built based on context Set property [See dude Expression variable](https://github.com/jbogard/EntityFramework.Filters/blob/c100a6e87d7e9cc172f4558d62e4d9d61dbbbff5/src/EntityFramework.Filters/FilterDefinitionFactory.cs#L13). I suppose you are doing retrieves of related items. Something like `Device.Descriptions` in that case it returns all related records without interception.

If you are using custom hardcoded values it would be better to use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID` in your filter, that will be standartized and in case of language change in the app filter would be changed at the same moment.

Comment: I'll try all approaches and suggestions asap and feedback your post. Thank you.

Comment: sorry about late response. I made a lots of tests here and I deduced that no matter how many time we `EnableFilter`, what is counting is `OnModelCreation` combined with this. Another thing I have deduced is that no matter if I use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID` or `CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture().Key` or `"AnyStaticValue"`, the first value is the only one filter considered. I guess there would have only one way to "fix" it - rerunning `OnModelCreation` when we have to change the filter. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry didn't get your idea? I wouldn't have much time next days? could you maybe sent me a shot project that has the issue at aspirin.gm(at)gmail.com. I'll take a look when I'll got some time

Comment: I've tried to store modelBuilder and initialize filter after one more time, but it doesn't helps. The only thing is that Filters should be enabled before `OnModelCreation` is raised. You should define who triggers that call and get rid of that

Comment: Exactly @Aspirin! But that's the point - `OnModelCreation` only runs once. Setting the filters before it's execution, the filters works as expected. The problem is that I may have to change filter value **AFTER** `OnModelCreation` execution. So, I found a possible workaround execution `System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();` all the time I have to change the filters. Still don't know if is a good approach, btw it's working. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That's why I was proposing to use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID` not as a parameter or store value in variable, but in the filter itself. Anyway, nice that it works for you. Good luck with your project

Comment: I tried to use LCID but once my culture was being set by Async method it was keeping the old value. Thank you so much.